# How can I append a linked list to the end of another?

Tags: java

I'm trying to join two linked lists together where the second list will be attached right after the tail of the first list. In my append method, I wanted to get the two lists that are to be joined together and then join the last list to the end. I'm having trouble assigning the current position to the head of the second list. Any suggestion on what my next step be?

```
public class Link {

public long dData;                 // data item
public Link next;                  // next link in list
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public Link(long d) // constructor
{
    dData = d;
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public void displayLink() // display this link
{
    System.out.print(dData + " ");
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------
}  // end class Link

public class FirstLastList {

private Link first;               // ref to first link
private Link last;                // ref to last link
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public FirstLastList() // constructor
{
    first = null;                  // no links on list yet
    last = null;
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public boolean isEmpty() // true if no links
{
    return first == null;
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public void insertFirst(long dd) // insert at front of list
{
    Link newLink = new Link(dd);   // make new link

    if (isEmpty()) // if empty list,
    {
        last = newLink;             // newLink <-- last
    }
    newLink.next = first;          // newLink --> old first
    first = newLink;               // first --> newLink
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public void insertLast(long dd) // insert at end of list
{
    Link newLink = new Link(dd);   // make new link
    if (isEmpty()) // if empty list,
    {
        first = newLink;            // first --> newLink
    } else {
        last.next = newLink;        // old last --> newLink
    }
    last = newLink;                // newLink <-- last
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public long deleteFirst() // delete first link
{                              // (assumes non-empty list)
    long temp = first.dData;
    if (first.next == null) // if only one item
    {
        last = null;                // null <-- last
    }
    first = first.next;            // first --> old next
    return temp;
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public void displayList() {
    System.out.print("List (first-->last): ");
    Link current = first;          // start at beginning
    while (current != null) // until end of list,
    {
        current.displayLink();      // print data
        current = current.next;     // move to next link
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public void append(FirstLastList list1, FirstLastList list2) {
    Link current = first;
    while (list1 != null) {
        current = current.next;
    }
    current.next = list2.first; 
}
}  // end class FirstLastList

public class FirstLastApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {                //make a new list
    FirstLastList theList = new FirstLastList();

    theList.insertFirst(22);       // insert at front
    theList.insertFirst(44);
    theList.insertFirst(66);

    theList.insertLast(11);        // insert at rear
    theList.insertLast(33);
    theList.insertLast(55);

    theList.displayList();         // display the list

    theList.deleteFirst();         // delete first two items
    theList.deleteFirst();

    theList.displayList();         // display again
    FirstLastList theList2 = new FirstLastList();

    theList.insertFirst(22);       // insert at front
    theList.insertFirst(44);
    theList.insertFirst(66);

    theList.insertLast(11);        // insert at rear
    theList.insertLast(33);
    theList.insertLast(55);

    theList.displayList();         // display the list

    theList.deleteFirst();         // delete first two items
    theList.deleteFirst();

    theList.displayList();         // display again

    append(theList, theList2);
    theList.displayList();         // display again


}  // end main()
}  // end class FirstLastApp
```

Answer (score 0):

in

> ```
> while (list1 != null) {
>     current = current.next;
> }
> ```

*list1* is unchanged, you will finish to dereference a NULL pointer

It is strange you get two lists in parameter while the operation is not static and doesn't return the result.

For me if not static the operation has to receive one list and to append it at the end of the current (this) list, iterating on the list in argument and adding each element using *insertLast*

You also receive the argument(s) by value, better to use reference to not copy it/them for nothing

Answer (score 0):

in append() method:

```
Link current = first;
while(current.next != null) {
    current = current.next;
}
current.next = list2.first;
```

When your current node reaches the last node, its `.next` would be null. That's when your join your 2nd list.